# Why pseudoconvexity is important in Partial differential equation theory?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, convexity

I am a new researcher in mathematics and I work on convexity. Are convexity and pseudoconvexity related topics and in which respect to PDE theory ? One of the important results in PDE theory is the Garding and Fefferman-Phon inequalities, so, I am asking if convexity or pseudoconvexity has an impact on these results.

Comment: You'll find a lot of this on the book of the master: Lars Hörmander, notions of convexity.